# Behaviour of system in special case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to describe the behaviour of the system

$$\dot x=2y+\frac{1}{8}\epsilon\alpha x \\
\dot y=-2x+\epsilon y^3\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

in the case that $\alpha=const.$

I already analyzed the case where $\epsilon=0$ but this was trivial. What can I do when $\epsilon\not=0$? I also do not see how to conclude that the system has any limit cyles for $0<\epsilon < 1$, if you have some ideas I really would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you doing Perturbation Analysis or Phase Portraits or any recent Theorems you may have learned?

Comment: I am familiar with both, Perturbation Theory and Phase Portraits so if there are any helpful Theorems it is no problem.

Comment: Can you find the critical points and then evaluate the Jacobian at each of them? Also, are you familiar with the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem?

Comment: Yes I know Poincare Bendixson, I am also able to evaluate the Jacobian at each of them but I have problems with the critical points. Setting both equation to zero I get $(0,0)$ as one critical points and some other, really bad looking ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a phase plane portrait of your system. There are sixteen initial conditions on the x-axis. Parameter "a" is set to 10, and epsilon is .1 . I'm not sure I can find a limit cycle. Integration is Runge-Kutta 4th order, step size .001.

Comment: But how to prove that there are non limit cycles? Maybe something wit Bendixson Theorem as Amzoti mentioned?

Comment: The first time I wrote down the system I used eps*a = 10 on both non-linear terms and a limit cycle popped up!